# How can I put all html related fields in the same line?

Tags: html, asp.net, xhtml

I have this form in one of my views:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

but I want some of this form fields be in the same line. How can I get this? I allready tried to put divs inside divs with ´style='style="margin: 0; padding: 0"'´ but I don't got anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` elements have `display:block` style by default. Block means that it expands to the whole width of the container and does not allow content to be in the same line (except for floating or absolutely positioned objects but that is not what you need for this).

You need to apply `display:inline-block` style to your label and field containers. Also you might need to add another `<div>` with the default display style that contains both the label and the field so that only one field is displayed per line.

See http://jsfiddle.net/a4Lwc/1/ for the sample.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactally that what I want. Now I have something like this and look great: `<fieldset>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div class="editor-label">
        Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Paola
    </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div class="editor-label">
        Number
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        14
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div class="editor-label">
        Date
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        14/11/2013
    </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>`

Answer (score 0):

You should assign float , when you use of float for div(or block elements) let to another element locate in side it

```
   <div class="editor-label" style=" float:left;">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label" style=" float:left;">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number)
    </div>
```